# JDBC Delete Conditional Statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

Something bugging me that I can't fix and would appreciate some help.

I am trying to from Java delete records where a condition is met. Below is the condition as working in MySQL:

```
Delete FROM bookingtable WHERE `Date` = '2016-04-23';
```

Now, trying to implement this into Java I have the below written (which doesn't work):

```
String s1 = "Delete FROM bookingtable " + "WHERE `Date` = "+formatted;
            System.out.println(s1);
```

My Sysout statement which I use for debugging prints out:

```
Delete FROM bookingtable WHERE `Date` = 2016-04-23
```

So it looks like I am on the right track except I need that date in apostrophes to make it work? - How do I actually go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add escape quotes around formatted:

```
String s1 = "Delete FROM bookingtable " + "WHERE `Date` = \"" + formatted + "\"";
```

Comment: Looks like the right idea but I now have this error `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column '2016-04-23' in 'where clause'`

Comment: okay, I fixed it by changing it to apostrophes! thanks    `String s1 = "Delete FROM bookingtable " + "WHERE `Date` = '" +formatted + "'";`

Comment: Those look like tick marks rather than single quote characters.

Comment: Use prepared statements, don't concatenate values into a query string.